# Meteor Slider - jump to slide

Tags: meteor-slides

I have an photo slide show and a body of text below the slider.  I would like to add a link to the text that will cause the slide show to jump to a specific slide.  I can't find anything on the support side and have not had any responses to my forum post.

Has anyone done this before? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this on the der help site:

This isn't that hard to do... Edit the `core/js/core.slider.js` file, and add the following on line 93:

`slider.data('cycle', cycle);`

That will add the slider's internal cycle object, used to control the slider's state, to the 'cycle' data property. Then, you can control the slider to do anything you want, when you want it.

You could do something like pause the slider, go to a specific slide, resume the slider, etc. You can see the API on the `core/js/core.cycle.js` file. Both Meteor Slider and VSlider implement it.

After you add the code above, you can do something like:

`<a onclick="jQuery('#myslider').data('cycle').goto(0);">Go to First Slide!</a>`

This assumes that you added an id of myslider to the element that has the slider-core class.

http://support.der-design.com/discussion/1894/jump-to-slide#Item_3

Comment: Ha, yes, I found that answer and implemented it, I just hadn't updated my question with the answer.  FYI, It works.